# Multiple a nested list cloumn by a value and then adding across the nested list column by a grouping variable

Tags: r

I have a large tibble with one nested list column. Each element of the nested list column has 10,000 iterations and i would like to apply a function to these elements and then sum across the elements by group.

I have created a minimal reproducible example below

```
tibble(a = list(c(1,2),c(3,4), c(5,6), c(7,8)),
   b = c(2,3, 4, 2),
   c = c(1,1, 2, 2))
```

I would first like to multiple each element in x$a with x$b. This should give me

```
tibble(a = list(c(2,4), c(9,12), c(20,24), c(14,16)),
   b = c(2,3, 4, 2),
   c = c(1,1,2,2))
```

Finally, i would like to group by x$c and then add across the values of the element of that group. This should give the following output

```
tibble(a = list(c(11,16), c(34,40)),
   c = c(1,2))
```

As you can see the first element of x$a is the sum of iterations where x$C==1 i.e. the sum of vector c(2,4) and c(9,12) giving c(11,14)

I think the purrr::map function can do this but struggling with the syntax here

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: hi akrun - so each value in each element of x$a is multiplied by x$b. The first element of x$a is c(1,2) multiplied by x$b[1] which is 2 giving c(2,4)

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it solves your problem. You did say that "any help would be greatly appreciated". 

Comment: Yes sorry indeed... Accepted thanks. Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option involving `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(a = map2(.x = a,
                 .y = b,
                 ~ .x * .y)) %>%
 group_by(c) %>%
 summarise(a = list(reduce(a, `+`)))

      c a        
  <dbl> <list>   
1     1 <dbl [2]>
2     2 <dbl [2]>
```

Answer (score 0):

We could convert to 'long' format by `unnest`ing the column 'a', do the multiplication and then `summarise` to get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
dat2 <- dat %>%
          mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
          unnest(c(a)) %>%
          group_by(rn) %>% 
          mutate(a1 = c(first(a) * first(b), last(a) * last(b))) %>% 
          group_by(c, grp = rowid(rn)) %>% 
          summarise(a = sum(a1))  %>%
          group_by(c) %>%
          summarise(a = list(a))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#      c a        
#   <dbl> <list>   
#1     1 <dbl [2]>
#2     2 <dbl [2]>
```

---

Or another option is to convert to wide format columns and then do the multiplication

```
dat %>% 
    unnest_wider(c(a)) %>% 
    group_by(c)  %>%
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with('..')), ~ sum(. * b))
```

---

Or in the devel version of `dplyr`

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
          unnest_wider(c(a)) %>% 
          group_by(c)  %>% 
          condense(a = across(starts_with('..'), ~ sum(. * b),
              names = "a{col}") %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE))

dat2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Rowwise:  c
#      c a        
#  <dbl> <list>   
#1     1 <dbl [2]>
#2     2 <dbl [2]>

dat2$a
#[[1]]
#[1] 11 16

#[[2]]
#[1] 34 40
```

---

In `base R` we can do

```
stack(lapply(split(Map(`*`, dat$a, dat$b), dat$c),
       function(x) do.call(`+`, x)))
#  values ind
#1     11   1
#2     16   1
#3     34   2   
#4     40   2
```

Answer (score 0):

And another option, using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = list(c(1,2),c(3,4), c(5,6), c(7,8)),
       b = c(2,3, 4, 2),
       c = c(1,1, 2, 2)) %>% 
      unnest() %>% 
      mutate(a = a*b) %>% 
      group_by(c) %>% 
      mutate(a = c(rep(nth(a,1) + nth(a,3), 2), rep(nth(a,2) + nth(a,4),2))) %>% 
      unique() %>% 
      summarize(a = list(a))

>       df
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      c a        
  <dbl> <list>   
1     1 <dbl [2]>
2     2 <dbl [2]>
```